# Check log file for access from Tor exit nodes

Tags: powershell, logging, tor

I am trying to write a script that will download the current Tor exit node list and check a local log file for access from Tor.

The code below outputs matches from Tor IPs in the log file to the console, but I would like to output the `Select-String` output in the `foreach` loop to a file (in addition to writing it to the console).

Once I have the results output to a file, I'll need to check the results to see if there was a match.

Any tips on how to output the `foreach` `Select-String` to a file and how to check for matches would be appreciated.

```
$source = "https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=[serverip]&port=[port]"
$dest = "C:\tor.txt"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $dest)
Get-Content "C:\tor.txt" | where { $_ -notmatch "^#" } | Set-Content "C:\filteredtor.txt"
Remove-Item "C:\tor.txt"
$list = get-content "C:\filteredtor.txt"
ForEach ($_ in $list) {Select-String "C:\logfile.log" -pattern $_}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Tee-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) cmdlet will save a copy of the input stream to a file while passing it to the output stream. Also, by using [`DownloadString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) instead of `DownloadFile()` you could streamline your code to a single pipeline and remove the need for temporary files:

```
$source  = 'https://...'
$log     = 'C:\logfile.log'
$results = 'C:\results.txt'

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
($wc.DownloadString($source)) -split "`n" | ? { $_ -notmatch '^(#|\s*$)' } | % {
  Select-String $log -pattern $_ | Tee-Object $results -Append
}

if ((Test-Path -LiteralPath $results) -and (Get-Content $results)) {
  # do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it is working. It finds the matches and writes them to the results.txt file as well as outputs them to the console. But in the PowerShell console (though not in the results.txt file) I get an error about an empty string:

Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is an empty string.
At C:\SysAdmin\checktorip.ps1:7 char:31

I'm wondering if maybe there is a blank line at the end of the Tor IP list, anyway to check for that and remove it if so?

Comment: @user51279 I updated the regular expression to exclude blank lines as well.

Comment: thanks for all your help.

One more question, is it possible to not output the Select-String to the powershell console and only write them to the results file?

Comment: @user51279 Sure. Just replace `Tee-Object` with `Out-File`, or use the appending redirection operator (`Select-String $log -pattern $_ >> $results`).